# how to open .html file with Chrome, to execute .js file?

Tags: javascript

Just started learning to code in JavaScript.

I referenced .js file via script source tag in .html file

When opening said .html file via Chrome, function in the .js file does not execute.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///Users/bob/Desktop/myScript.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<h1>External JavaScript</h1>

<p id="demo">A Paragraph.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p>(myFunction is stored in an external file called "myScript.js")</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Content of .js file

```
function myFunction()
{
document.getElementbyId(“demo”).innerHTML="changed";}
```

Codes typed in TextEdit (host platform: MacOs X)

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: no code = no answer

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Comment: fix the typos and the code will work, see the answer and comments on it

Answer (score 0):

this code works, you have some typos:

in file:

```
function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="changed";
}
```

in html:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///Users/bob/Desktop/myScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="demo">A Paragraph.</p>
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
</body>
</html>
```

see comments below

Comment: I've altered my codes in the original post, but still doesn't work.

Comment: you have typos in the quotes around demo, and in the javascript function...   do not use italicized quotes (these: “ ”), use reqular quotes double or single (these " ", or ' ')...  you have a typo in getElementById, "by" must be capitalized--> getElementById not getElementbyId

Comment: Thanks @me_  - i seriously don't know what on earth went on. As I tried for many hours, the script just didn't work. After having restarted the computer for other tasks and clearing the browser cache, the script works with the same code (in this case, I'm using relative path via naming the source file directly within the script source tag). Beats me. Thank you so much anyway for chipping in. Much appreciated. p.s. installed Sublime Text and some JS plugins for build systems but when it ran successfully, I was merely running BbEdit.

Comment: this is the correct answer--the pat on the back is nice, the green check mark showing the answer is accepted is nicer ;)

Comment: side note: to reset code in the browser (in chrome at least) if you have the dev console open right click on the refresh button and choose hard reload or empty cache and hard reload